# How to get useful files from a github package?

Tags: github, atom-editor

Although I've been using github for a while, but every now and then this problem pops up. From a github project, how do I know which filed/folders are actually what I need?(Generally, I don't need those files that are only used by developers)

Take this project (https://github.com/mupchrch/split-diff) for example, I am trying to install this plugin into my Atom editor so I can compare two files, but I find very little is said about how and which files are to be installed/copied, and to where. This "lack" of information happens to many many github projects I stumbled with. Some indicates `npm install xxx` which I am OK with, some says nothing at all, like the above example. So I conclude I must have missed some very important information regarding how to use github package, something that goes without saying.

Can anyone help me or give me any hint?

I noticed that here is a package.json file, which must indicate this package can be installed by npm. But I need more specific instructions:
Do I need to download all the files and folders? To where? And where do I launch `npm install`? Or as far as I know, Atom editor has its own install command (`apm` is it?), where do I run this `apm`?

Comment: "I don't need those files that are only used by developers" - Are you aware that git, and with it git-hub, is a tool for developers to manage their source code? It's not a software distribution site. That's why you often won't find installables, or any binaries, among the source code in a repository. Those just don't really belong there, just like you don't use an email account for your regular system backups; you probably could, but it's not made for it.

Comment: But when you try to download some software, very often they only direct you to github website. It is actually being used as software distribution in many cases.

Comment: @JimmyB Even so there is gotta be a way for developers to tell which files are for distribution and which files are for developement, right?

Comment: If a developer decides to put binaries into the repository there's still no way to automatically detect them; if you're lucky, you find textual instructions.

Comment: In fact, as a developer, I'd be bugged if I had to check out (download) a bunch of binaries with the source code from a source code repository each time (possibly multiple times a day on an active project). - So, sorry, but I don't think there is *any* standard way of providing binaries associated with github.

Comment: OTOH, there are certain conventions of where binaries are put during the build process, as well as which file types those binaries have, .exe or .dll files for example for native windows programs, or .jar files for Java applications, or the "target" folder maven creates, or "Release" folder in a C project. But those conventions are vastly differing between languages and tools and cannot be relied upon. So, indeed, when I see a .jar file or a "target" folder in a repository, I go "*sigh*, someone checked in the binaries again...".